# Having two webviews in my app one webview not unable to delete conent in webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have two webviews in my android app one webview deletes content based on given javascript function and other one is remaining same even I give javascript function by id. The main webview working perfectly and other one not and now i may integrating another webview if my second webview works perfectly.

here is my first webview it's working perfectly

```js
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("url");
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true)



    public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() {document.getElementById('mainHeader').style.display='none';" + "document.getElementById('footerRights').style.display='none';" + "document.getElementById('navTrail').style.display='none';" + "document.getElementById('threeColumns').style.display='none';" + " })()");

        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }


        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

        }


    }


    @Override
    // This method is used to detect back button
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            // Let the system handle the back button
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

my second webview

```js
  

public class webview2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webVIEW;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);

        webVIEW = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webVIEW);
        webVIEW.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webVIEW.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webVIEW.loadUrl("example url");
        webVIEW.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webVIEW.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }

    public class webVIEW extends WebViewClient {

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " + "var element = document.getElementById('hplogo');" + "element.parentNode.removeChild(element);" + " })()");
        }


        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon ) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
    }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        if (webVIEW.canGoBack()) {
            webVIEW.goBack();
        }else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

webview2.java

its being remaining same no javascript excution now i need to integrate another webview and it also needs the same as first webview

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my question using kotlin class by this i can inject java script in one or more webviews

```js
class webview2 : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var webVIEW: WebView

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview)



        webVIEW = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webVIEW) as WebView


        webVIEW.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webVIEW.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
                injectJS()
            }
        }
        webVIEW.loadUrl("https://example/login")
    }


    val progressBar = findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.progressBar3)
    



    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (webVIEW.canGoBack()) {
            webVIEW.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }

    private fun injectJS() {
        val jsContent: String?
        jsContent = try {
            val inputStream = assets.open("style.js")
            val fileContent = inputStream.bufferedReader().use(BufferedReader::readText)
            inputStream.close()
            fileContent
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            null
        }
        jsContent?.let { webVIEW.loadUrl("javascript:($jsContent)()") }
    }
}
```